# Django and facebook login: can't get 'code' variable in callback

Tags: django, facebook

here's my view.py

```
def facebook_login(request):
    f = FacebookAPI(client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID, client_secret=FACEBOOK_API_SECRET, redirect_uri=SITE_URL+'/login/facebook/')
    if request.GET.has_key('code'):
        code = request.GET.get('code')
        logger.debug(code)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

`code` variable is always empty here. When I'm trying to access it manually it works ok, I get `code` in this way.
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.bar.net%2Flogin%2Ffacebook/&client_id=123456789`

I'm using the next [library](https://github.com/michaelhelmick/requests-facebook) for working with FB API

Not sure what's wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I have found the issue, so lame. The fix is below:

```
def facebook_login(request):
    if request.GET.has_key('code'):
        code = request.GET.get('code')
        logger.debug(+code)
    else:
        redirect_url = 'https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='+FACEBOOK_APP_ID+'&redirect_uri='+SITE_URL+'/login/facebook/'
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login.html')
```